# How to show image on another image on click while there are multiple images with same class name using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of videos with thumbnails which is generating using loop and making a playlist.

Here is the code of jquery

```
 var div = $('#div_thumbnails');
 div.html('');
 $('.cjtp-hp-video').each(function(i, video){ 
     var src = $(video).find('img').attr('src');
     var index = $(video).attr('data-index');
     var title = $(video).find('.cjtp-hp-title').text();
     var thumbnail = '<img class="thumbnail" src="'+src+'" data-index="'+index+'" data-title="'+title+'">';
     div.append(thumbnail);
 });
```

This loop is making this HTML:

```
<div class="div_thumbnails">
   <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="0" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
   <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="1" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
   <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="2" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
   <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="3" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
</div>
```

Here is the Css

```
#div_thumbnails {
    height: 110px;
    border-width: 2px 2px 0px 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I am changing the image selected style on first click on image using jquery using this code :

```
$(document).find('#div_thumbnails').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var css = { 'outline': '', 'outline-offset': '' };

    $('#div_thumbnails').find('img').not(this).css(css).animate({opacity: "0.3"}, 500);

    if (index != $(this).attr('data-index'))
        clicked=0;

    index = $(this).attr('data-index');
    clicked++;
    if (clicked === 1) {
        var title = $(this).attr('data-title');
        $('#span_thumbnails_title').html(title);
    } else if (clicked === 2) {
        core.playVideo(index);
        clicked = 0;
    }
});
```

Now please tell me how can i show an play video icon image over this selected image usign jquery or javascript?

Comment: Which icon do you want to show exactly? Where is it coming from?

Comment: i want to show traingle play icon over image which is stored in my images folder.

Comment: @Armel do you have any solution?

Comment: @Armel can you help me on this question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297252/how-to-generate-pdf-from-dynamic-html-using-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions for that. You could try to change the function generating your HTML by adding a `div` that is going to wrap your thumbnail and then add a play icon when the mouse enters the wrapper.

I implemented a CSS solution for your case:

```js
var $wrappers = $('.thumbnail_wrapper');

$wrappers.on('click', function () {
  $wrappers.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.thumbnail_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail_wrapper.active::after {
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 85px;
  left: 155px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_thumbnails">
  <div class="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="0" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="1" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="2" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail_wrapper">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YHLZitYYyIg/mqdefault.jpg" data-index="3" data-title="Vsauce enters The Create Unknown – Vsauce2 po..." style="opacity: 1;outline: white solid 3px;outline-offset: -3px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But i want this play button on first click. How can i do that?

Comment: @FahadHassanSubzwari I have added a little piece of JS so the icon shows up on click.

Comment: But from where i can change the size of that play button image?

Comment: In the CSS, check the `border` size.

Comment: Can you help me on this [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297252/how-to-generate-pdf-from-dynamic-html-using-node-js) ?

Comment: Sorry I can't, the question is `on hold`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187116/discussion-between-fahad-hassan-subzwari-and-armel).